# Using Play! 2.0.4 with Play2war plugin

Tags: java, plugins, playframework-2.0, war

So I am developing an app with Play 2.0.4 and I need to create a WAR file. I tried using the Play2War plugin but I have no idea how to set it up.

I tried following the configuration ( *https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Configuration* )
but it's all to cryptic for me, and nothing seems to work?

Does anyone have an idiot proof guide? Where should I put the Play2war folder I downloaded?

Best regards, Ba.

Comment: I just need to deploy the app on a Glassfish or an Apache server, if that is possible without the WAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly honest the play2-war-plugin documentation is pretty comprehensive. But to break things down a little more, here is the *bare minimum* you need to do to make the `helloworld` sample app build as a WAR file that can be hosted in a Servlet 2.5 container. You don't need to download anything manually as such, and only two project files need to be edited:

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Play2war plugins release" at "http://repository-play-war.forge.cloudbees.com/release/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % Option(System.getProperty("play.version")).getOrElse("2.0"))

addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "0.8.1")
```

**project/Build.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._
import com.github.play2war.plugin._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "helloworld"
    val appVersion      = "1.0"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here
      Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "2.5"
    ).settings(Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings: _*)

}
```

Once you've made those edits, you should be able to generate a WAR file by running the following command from the `helloworld` directory:

```
play war
```

There might be a neater way of listing this plugin in `Build.scala` instead, but this should get you going.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thank you for the good instructions.

Answer (score 0):

on console: play war [app] -o app.war. I think it should work